# Weird question mark sign after casting object to array

Tags: php

I am trying to cast an object to array, to use its protected properties.
Unfortunately, the array keys contain some wierd looking question marks so I cannot use these values in my code. The error says "undefined index of array".

Where does it come from and what can I do about it?

Object var_dump:

```
object(testClassName)#35 (2) {
  ["name":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["path":protected]=>
  string(9) "files/"
```

Typecast:

```
$object = new testClassName();
$array = (array) $object;
```

Array var_dump:

```
array(2) {
  ["�*�name"]=>
  NULL
  ["�*�path"]=>
  string(9) "files/"
}
```

Comment: does this still happen if you change the properties to be public?

Comment: i don't know if others would disagree but for me if it's protected it shouldn't be accessible without some kind of method to return them.  I'd suggest a method called `getArray()` which returns the values you want

Comment: weird signs usually indicate an encoding problem. Long story short - multi-bytes saved as Latin1 etc and opened as utf-8. It could also be "wild" white space (like \r\n) - what to do depends on how precious this signs are - can you just preg_replace them? If not, check what the encoding is, there are free online converters.